# Где взять Blend для Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Не могу найти Expression Blend для Visual Studio 2015. Вроде бы пишут люди, что он входит в состав VS, но я не могу его найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел. В Visual studio меню *Вид* - *Проектировать в Blend*

Просто раньше он был отдельным приложением, которое я запускал из меню Пуск

Answer (score 1):

Да, он входит в VS. Попробуйте открыть проект из папки, а не из Visual Studio.(Я так делаю)

Comment: Я не понял вас. Какая разница откуда я открываю проект? Скажите где находится Expression Blend

Comment: Когда открываете проект из общей папки с другими проектами, ваш проект откроется в Blend, а не в VS.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вам кто-то чего-то настроил и вы теперь не сами понимаете что именно у вас происходит

Comment: Нет,  никто ничего не настраивал. Возможно, установилось по умолчанию.